# Grep numbers from a string

Tags: python, regex

There is a way a grep only numbers from a string?

For example:

```
a = "abcd1.34-poytr"
```

I want to grep only "1.34"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions for the win:

```
import re

s = "sdfsdsf3.657ddsfdsfdsfdsd-12dfdsfsdfsd-67.34fdsfsfss"
re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|[-+]?\d+", s)
```

Output:

```
>> ['3.657', '-12', '-67.34']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for that:

```
import re

a = "abcd1.34-poytr"

re.findall(r'\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?', a)
```

#### EXAMPLE

```
import re

a = "abcd1.34-poytr23w12"

print re.findall(r'\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?', a)

[OUTPUT]
['1.34', '23', '12']
```

Comment: Everything after the decimal is optional (for a general case).

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` inside `[..]`.

Comment: @falsetru, Thank you. I always get confused on that one. :)

Comment: @user3634982, I updated my answer a bit after your last comment. You might want to see it again. Glad I could help.